# What should I do when I get "Lens Error Restart Camera"?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, error, powershot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do about Canon PowerShot “Lens error, restart camera”?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11755/what-should-i-do-about-canon-powershot-lens-error-restart-camera)

I have a PowerShot SX20is that started to throw this error out of the blue:

> `Lens Error Restart Camera`

Any suggestions what can be done here?

Comment: Can you provide some additional information? What kinds of things were you doing when the error appeared? Does restarting fix it/not fix it? What have you tried to do to fix it so far? The more information you provide us, the better equipped we can be to help. :)

Comment: Restart the camera?

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy. That error happened to me on a Powershot SX100 is some weeks ago. I visited several web sites like [this one](http://camerarepair.blogspot.com/2007/12/fixing-lens-error-on-digital-camera.html) but wasn't able to fix it by myself, so I ended up buying the same camera you have (was also an excuse to buy a new one), and pray it doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

If the camera is still in the warranty, you should return it. There does not seem to be a real fix for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the camera's battery.  Also read the camera's manual to see if it has a secondary 'watch' style battery hidden away somewhere too.  If so, remove that too.

Leave the camera well alone for around 1 hour.  Replace (if you had it) the watch battery, followed by the main battery.  Then turn the camera on and see if it did the trick.

I cannot guarantee that this will work for you, but when my EOS 7D was experiencing really weird issues, this is what I did and for whatever reason completely fixed the problem!

Also, ensure that the camera and lens - as far as possible - is clean and free from dirt before you put the batteries back in.