# How can I fix a Nikon Coolpix L120 stuck lens error?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting

I am getting an error in my Nikon Coolpix L120: "Turn off the camera, remove the lens cover and then turn the camera on", even though i have already removed the lens cover.

The lens is not able to come outside. I don't know how to solve this problem. I know it is still in warranty period, but I brought it from some other country, other than the current country of stay. Is the Nikon warranty worldwide or countrywise?

Comment: You might find this info helpful: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11755/what-should-i-do-about-canon-powershot-lens-error-restart-camera

Comment: Today took the camera to nikon service center. They tell the lens has gone bad without even checking properly. I don't know what to do now.

Comment: http://camerarepair.blogspot.in/2007/12/fixing-lens-error-on-digital-camera.html

Comment: If Nikon was smart they would do worldwide, If that were my cam, I take it apart to make sure everything was working as it should be! From what you said, it sounds like it a sensor on the inside! this is looking like something you might have to send or take in to get fix! not sure if that model you have has a reset on it, sometimes taken out the battery as well as the one on the inside will reset it to factory settings! I hope this help out! good luck

Answer (score 1):

Nikon lenses may carry a one-year worldwide warranty, but their cameras do not. Almost every camera company protects their national and regional distributor networks by creating warranties that are limited to where the camera is bought.

Typically 'lens errors' are caused by something hitting the lens, or something getting stuck inside of it. Some cameras are fairly robust, and can withstand being dropped on their nose, while others will break simply by being powered on inside of a close-fitting case. This will be called "user damage" or "abuse", and is not covered under warranty, which applies only to defects in materials or manufacturing.

In my experience from working in a camera store there are only two possible outcomes for a compact camera that stops working: it is repaired at no cost by the powers-that-be or it is disposed of by the owner. These devices are made thousands at a time by machine, but they're fixed one at a time by trained technicians. Paying to have one repaired simply isn't cost-effective compared to the purchase price of a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try methods by yourself. they're not a very serious methods and I don't know if will work or not, but here it is:

http://www.wikihow.com/Repair-Lens-Problems-on-Your-Digital-Camera
(Go to the 'Last-Ditch Efforts' section)

Let me know if works or not.