# Is there a quality compact camera with AA batteries?

Tags: battery

When my wife has retired later this year we intend to hit the road big time. We are aiming to travel light (single hand luggage bag) so I want a compact rather than my DSLR. I also insist on AA batteries as cannot guarantee access to recharge options.
Having trouble finding almost anything that isn't rechargeable batteries. Is there anything decent? Or will I have to buy an older second hand model?

Comment: Voting to close as opinion based - "anything decent" isn't so personal to you that we can't give a useful answer.

Comment: Long ago in a galaxy far, far away...

Comment: My opinion is that you will actually make your life much easier by not wrestling against the trend of rechargeable batteries. If you wind up somewhere with a dead battery, so be it. Consider bringing an additional rechargeable battery. I'd love to know where you plan on going where they sell AA batteries but don't have electrical outlets ;)

Comment: Get a power inverter for your car.  http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Apower%20inverter

Comment: Also relevant: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50178/why-do-cameras-use-proprietary-batteries and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42727/is-there-a-special-term-for-cameras-that-use-standard-replaceable-batteries

Comment: @MatthewWhited "hit the road" was probably figurative given hand luggage only. There probably is no car.

Comment: Maybe, their is a reason i didnt post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there are still many compact cameras that use AA batteries.

Here is a camera search link that allows you to search only cameras with AA batteries: [DP Review Camera Search](http://www.dpreview.com/products/search/cameras?utm_campaign=internal-link&utm_source=mainmenu&utm_medium=text&ref=mainmenu#criterias=SpecsCoreParams%2CSpecsBatteryNew&paramSpecsCoreParamsBodyType=UltraCompact%2CCompact%2CLargeSensorCompact%2CSLRLikeCompact%2CRangefinderStyleMirrorless%2CSLRStyleMirrorless%2CCompactSLR%2CMidSizeSLR%2CLargeSLR&paramSpecsBatteryNew=AA) (under "Physical" you can select AA batteries)

All these cameras use AA batteries

[image]