# Lens Error on a Powershot sx30 IS

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, repair, error, powershot

I have a Canon Powershot SX30IS and I keep getting a lens error. I was taking pics outside on a clear cold day in wintertime and my camera just displayed that message and shut down. I powered my camera back up, took a few more pics, and then the same message came up again. I have not been able to take a photo since. My camera will not even open to give me a chance to power it off. It will do this with the same error message. Is there anyway I can fix this myself, as the camera is about 6 years old?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do about Canon PowerShot "Lens error, restart camera"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11755/what-should-i-do-about-canon-powershot-lens-error-restart-camera)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the lens error is a result of some sort of impact force on the lens, which breaks small plastic lens track material inside the lens itself, causing guide pins to 'jam' and deter the gear mechanism and motor from driving the lens properly.  This can also occur if dust or debris gets into the lens' inner and outer casing sheath. A small can of compressed air may be useful in dislodging the debris or dirt, but if there is a broken part inside, that will require disassembly and a great deal of skill. A persons without advanced skills in repairing electronics probably should *not* attempt this!

A lot of camera repair shops can do this repair but depending on the extend of the damage to the lens, it's not a sure fix due to the lack of available parts. Some vendors on eBay sell these parts for experienced repair people to use, but then again, buying from unknown sources may mean you are buying a broken lens assembly, negating the good price you paid.

In any case, try the canned air first, but also be advised that this operation possibly can blow some debris deeper into the lens body and cause image issues due to the debris blocking light from subjects being photographed!

Good luck! These are nice cameras but fragile and with a great deal of issues with 'lens errors' for sure. "Handle [it] like eggs", as the brits wrote on aircraft gyro's in fighter aircraft, and I do mean that!