# Preventing (Powershot) lens error

Tags: lens, troubleshooting, point-and-shoot, error, powershot

How can I prevent a Canon Powershot [lens error](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/11755/8320)?  I've had them three times with three different cameras.  Twice after dropping, but last time not even that.  Note that last time was with a different camera, that I did not drop.  It may have been the Icelandic volcanic dust; the final days the cover would not close or open properly, and the final minutes the light sensor had a dark bias.  I was extra annoyed it happened in the middle of a wilderness trek so I lack photos for the final week, as I did not manage to fix it (I may or may not fix it yet).

What are some good strategies of preventing a Canon Powershot lens error, or indeed the identical problem in other cameras?

Comment: You could probably start by not dropping your camera. Your subsequent problems could very well be related to the previous drops.

Comment: @MichaelClark The previous drops were with different cameras.  I've never dropped my current camera.  Edited for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. At first it sounded like it was all the same camera.

Comment: Perhaps you could share some images displaying your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As stated by others, don't drop your camera (@MichaelClark). Although you may not recall dropping it, it may have sustained impacts while protected from obvious external damage, such as from within a backpack.
- The camera may have been switched on while the lens was blocked from extending. For instance, from within a backpack. If this happens repeatedly, the motor or other mechanisms could be damaged.

Preventive measures:

- Be aware that bags don't always protect what is contained within them.
- Get a protective case that allows the camera to be used from within the case.
- Get a rugged camera.
- Remove the battery before putting the camera inside a small case, so that the camera cannot be switched on accidentally. (@flolilolilo)